# Outlook 365 EAS to Exchange 2013 server issue

Tags: exchange-server, outlook-2016

Can anyone please help me if Outlook 365 is able to connect to Exchange 2013 server using EAS? When i try to configure Outlook 365, i am getting the below error. 
"Log onto Exchange ActiveSync mail server (EAS): The server cannot be found"

Please note that AutoDiscover is configured in DNS. Please Help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Exchange 2013 version did you use (which SP & CU?)

Comment: Exchanage 2013 With SP1 & CU6

Comment: CU6 is very old (Dec. 2014). You miss multiple security upgrades and improvements. So before we do here any in deep troubleshooting I would prefer if you bring the environment to a recent version which plays better with the cloud stuff as an 3 year old environment.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I have figured out the issue. This particular domain name was not resolving from this particular users PC which is because of client side network issues. To resolve this issue we changed the DNS client IP and reconfigured outlook.

Comment: Ok please Post that as answer and accept it. The such one is nonlonger marked as an open question and the community could focus on the open one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your support. I have figured out the issue. This particular domain name was not resolving from this particular users PC which is because of client side network issues. To resolve this issue we changed the DNS client IP and reconfigured outlook